# Bypass github branch protection in github actions for changes in the documentation

Tags: github, github-actions, branch

**Situation**: I have a github repository where branch protection is enabled and set for two reviewers.
**Request**: It should be possible to bypass this branch protection with github actions, so that when the documentation is changed, only one reviewer is needed.

As far as my research goes, it is possible to completely bypass the branch protection rules with github actions. Since this is not the requested feature, and bypassing branch protection all together is a major security issue, this option is off the table.
Another possible solution I thought of (based on the solution above) is disabeling the branch protection, awaiting the review and then enabeling the branch protection again (all in github actions). The problem I see here, is that while branch protection is disabled we once again have a major security issue.

Is there any way to set the branch protection (or have a workaround with github actions), so that when only the docs folder is changed, only one review is needed?

Comment: Not the cleanest [idea](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-branch-protection) but it can work. This [one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/review-assign-action) looks best to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bot (service account) that's added as codeowner of the repository and in a GH Action detects if the PR only changes documentation this service account approves the PR, hence requiring only one more approval

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35523328)